# Save all edit on a form with button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form with multiple inputs, checkboxes, textarea, etc. On button click I want to execute a save values for any element that may have changed.

Due to my user base I can't always guarantee that they will press ENTER or TAB. So the button will be labeled SAVE CHANGES.

The problem is that without leaving an input element or pressing ENTER the new value is not actually written into the input, and therefore the SAVE BUTTON does not now the input value has changed.

So. How to implement code that scrubs all elements for any value changes. Something that forces all inputs to be updated with new values.

Remember that the user will edit a value and immediately select SAVE button without an ENTER or exit from the element.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem, because when you edit the text in input/textareas, the values are available to javascript even when you don't enter/tab.

Comment: Yes the values are in the element. However, how do you  know which element changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your script that saves every event that occurs in the input as follows

Jquery

```
$("input").change(function(){
  alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

Javascript

```
  object.addEventListener("change", myScript);
```

You could also review the documentation for keyup events so that it is saved every time the user changes the value or when the user presses a key. It could be useful in some cases.

Comment: I have code in the form that is triggered when the user presses ENTER. At that time we know which element it is by using "this.id". 

As I stated before, the issue arises when the user does not press ENTER and goes straight to the SAVE BUTTON. Since the user did not press ENTER the code is not executed. 

Hence my question. I have not been able to find a way to trap which element has been edited because 'this.id' returns the ID of the button.

Sure I could assume that all have been edited and therefore save all values over an over again. That is terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to load all the records data retrieved into an array. Then, before exit collect all the current values on the form in another array.

When the user selects another record do a diff on the arrays and voila we have the pairs that need saving. I left the form on change as well for when the user edits a value and presses ENTER.

This way we hope to catch any changes. The new function called  is also called on the Windows.beforeunload.